# Python scalars convert one Arrary

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am getting the error below when running the Pytorch model. How can I convert into one size-1 array, please? here my code below: I have had a look at other StackOverflow answers but couldn't figure out how to do it. Sorry if this question is very basic. I hope someone can help. Many Thanks in advance!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train3_Eval.py", line 177, in 
print("MAE Total: %f" % MAE_for_all_epochs)
TypeError: must be real number, not list

```
# main training loop
global_step = 0
best_test_error = 10000
MAE_for_all_epochs = []
MSE_for_all_epochs = []
for epoch in range(4):
    print("Epoch %d" % epoch)
    model.train()
    for images, paths in tqdm(loader_train):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
        targets = targets.float().to(device)

        # forward pass:
        output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
        preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)
        
        # backward pass:
        loss = torch.mean((preds - targets)**2)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # logging:
        count_error = torch.abs(preds - targets).mean()
        writer.add_scalar('train_loss', loss.item(), global_step=global_step)
        writer.add_scalar('train_count_error', count_error.item(), global_step=global_step)

        print("Step %d, loss=%f, count error=%f" % (global_step,loss.item(),count_error.item()))

        global_step += 1
    
    mean_test_error = 0
    model.eval()
    for images, paths in tqdm(loader_test):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
        targets = targets.float().to(device)

        # forward pass:
        output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
        preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)

        # logging:
        #error = torch.abs(preds - targets).sum().data
        #squared_error = ((preds - targets)*(preds - targets)).sum().data

        #runnning_mae += error
        #runnning_mse += squared_error

        loss = torch.mean((preds - targets)**2)
        count_error = torch.abs(preds - targets).mean()
        mean_test_error += count_error
        writer.add_scalar('test_loss', loss.item(), global_step=global_step)
        writer.add_scalar('test_count_error', count_error.item(), global_step=global_step)
        
        global_step += 1
        #store_MAE = 0
        #store_MSE = 0

        mean_test_error = mean_test_error.detach() / len(loader_test)
        #store_MAE += mean_test_error
        MAE_for_all_epochs.append(mean_test_error)

        mse = math.sqrt(loss / len(loader_test))
        #store_MSE +=mse
        MSE_for_all_epochs.append(mse)

        print("Test count error: %f" % mean_test_error)
        print("MSE: %f" % mse)

    if mean_test_error < best_test_error:
        best_test_error = mean_test_error
        torch.save({'state_dict':model.state_dict(),
                    'optimizer_state_dict':optimizer.state_dict(),
                    'globalStep':global_step,
                    'train_paths':dataset_train.files,
                    'test_paths':dataset_test.files},checkpoint_path)

print("MAE Total: %f" % MAE_for_all_epochs)
print("MSE Total: %f" % MSE_for_all_epochs)

model_mae= MAE_for_all_epochs / epoch
model_mse= MSE_for_all_epochs / epoch
print("Model MAE: %f" % model_mae)
print("Model MSE: %f" % model_mse)
```

Comment: What is the value of `model_mae`? Please, update with `model_mae.shape` too. As it is, `MAE_for_all_epochs` seems to be an `np.array` with multiple values, but then you'd get an error before when you try to print it.

Comment: model_mae should only contain one value, but the code seems to fail before getting to this part. MAE_for_all_epochs should contain all store values for MAE. I am not sure if i should add those values instead of appending them?

Comment: I understand what they should be. Based on your error, we need to know they *actually* are to help you. If, in fact, they are lists, I wouldn't expect this code to work, but then an error message should be thrown earlier.

Comment: Python formatting like ` %f" % ...` only works with one number, a scalar.  Or a bit more generally a `numpy` array with only one numeric element.  It is puzzling why `model_mae` gives a problem, but `MAE_for_all_epochs` does not.

Comment: You start `MAE_for_all_epochs = []`, but I don't see a `MAE_for_all_epochs.append(...)`.  Instead you use `np.append` which is slower, and harder to use right.   In any case, when debugging, don't depend on guesses and expected results.  Check actual values at key points; especially make sure array `shape` (and dtype) is right.

Comment: I have the following traceback error message now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train3_Eval.py", line 177, in <module>
    print("MAE Total: %f" % MAE_for_all_epochs)
TypeError: must be real number, not list